# How to add footer in Grid in sencha

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is my view part as PurchaseReport.js

```
Ext.define("App.view.tabs.PurchaseReport", {
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
alias: "widget.PurchaseReportTab",
requires: [
        "App.model.PurchaseReport", "Ext.toolbar.Toolbar"
],
border: false,
layout: "fit",
items: [
    App.Util.buildBrowseConfig({}, {
        controller: "PurchaseReport",
        primaryKeyField: "PurchaseReportId",
        stateful: true,
        stateId: "App.view.windows.PurchaseReport-grid",

        columns: [
          { dataIndex: "PurchaseCost", filter: true, header: "Purchase Cost", width: 150 }
        ],
        features: [{ ftype: "filters", autoReload: false, local: true }],
        store: { model: "App.model.PurchaseReport", sorters: [{ property: "Name", direction: "asc" }] }
    })
]
```

});

This is my controller part where my grid get bind as PurchaseReport.js,
**So do I need to make changes over here?**

```
Ext.define("App.controller.tabs.PurchaseReport", {
extend: "Ext.ux.app.BrowseController",
views: ["tabs.PurchaseReport"],
refs: [
    {
        ref: "myPurchaseReportGrid",
        selector: "PurchaseReportTab > gridpanel"
    }
],

init: function () {
    this.control({
        PurchaseReportTab: {
            bind: function (a, c) {
             **//Grid bind start**
                var b = this.getMyPurchaseReportGrid();
                b.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                b.store.removeAll();
                b.fireEvent("bind", b, c)
                **//Grid bind End**

             **//Combobox Bind start**
                var combo = this.getCoachCombo(),
                      store = combo.store,
                      options = store.lastOptions || {};
                options = Ext.apply({
                    callback: function () {
                        combo.select(App.coach.CoachId)
                        //console.log("called rajesh");
                    }
                }, options);
                store.load(options);
                if (App.coach.IsAdmin) {
                    combo.show()
                }
                **//Combobox Bind end**


                var abilities = App.coach.Abilities,
                      toolbar = this.getToolbar();
                for (var x = 0; x < abilities.length; x++) {

                    var ability = abilities[x],
                        button = toolbar.query("button[tooltip=" + ability.Name + "]");
                    if (button.length) {
                        button[0].setVisible(true)
                    }
                }

            }
        },

        "PurchaseReportTab > gridpanel": {
            bind: this.bind,
            itemdblclick: this.handleRecord,
            selectionchange: this.selectionChange
        }


    })
}
```

});

This is my model part name as PurchaseReport.js

```
 Ext.define("App.model.PurchaseReport", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: [
    {
        name: "PurchaseDate",
        type: "date"
    }
],

proxy: {
    type: "ajax",
    url: "ControllerFactory.aspx",
    extraParams: {
        controller: "PurchaseReport",
        operation: "GetPurchaseReportsByCoachIdAndDates"
    },
    reader: {
        type: "json",
        root: "data",
        successProperty: "success"
    }
}
```

});

However I am able to get the record display in grid view but I need a footer area where I can display **Total amount of Purchase cost**. in footer of grid

Please do not find mistake of code as I had deleted many stuff to make it look simpler, as i am new in this please make me know which more details are being needed.

Just a Image for more detail
[image]

I have tried adding code as but it is displaying footer in all pages where the Gridview is displaying record, **I want to display footer in one page only and not on other pages and also need total of purchase cost displaying on that**

```
Ext.define("Ext.grid.Panel", {
extend: "Ext.panel.Table",
requires: ["Ext.grid.View"],
alias: ["widget.gridpanel", "widget.grid"],
alternateClassName: ["Ext.list.ListView", "Ext.ListView", "Ext.grid.GridPanel"],
viewType: "gridview",
lockable: false,
bothCfgCopy: ["invalidateScrollerOnRefresh", "hideHeaders", "enableColumnHide", "enableColumnMove", "enableColumnResize", "sortableColumns"],
normalCfgCopy: ["verticalScroller", "verticalScrollDock", "verticalScrollerType", "scroll"],
lockedCfgCopy: [],
rowLines: true,
  //Newly addded start
 height: 200,
 width: 400,

 bbar: [
        {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Total',
        fieldLabel: 'Total',
        allowBlank: false 
        }
            ],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 //Newly addded end
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

For placing footer you need to use `bbar` in your code. In your code where you define grid and its config there you need to write

sample example :

```
 bbar: [
        {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Total',
        fieldLabel: 'Total',
        allowBlank: false 
        }
    ],
```

Please read  [Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html)  for better understanding.
Also I make a fiddle for you so you can correlate your project and grid. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hrc)

Comment: I need to apply this footer for particular page only, So I have to add this code on view Part?(My version of sencha is 4.1)

Comment: then you can try this :`b.bbar` and add you code in that. Yes that is fine for ext version 4.

Comment: Where should I write this b.bar, I have tried adding bbar code in Ext.grid.Panel and its showing total textbox down of ever page where grid is there . please review update question where i had added bbar

Comment: That place is correct where you using bbar. You want on some perticular page right. I was asking to put where you place `bbar` where you are bind the data. Well let me think again.

Comment: I am binding data in grid on controller part. Please review comment as **//Grid bind start** in controller part. As I am new in sencha I needed more detail for where to place code and all, pls don't mind

Comment: Ya, trying to understand, btw one quick question what is meaning of this ...  
"I need to apply this footer for particular page only,"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124895/discussion-between-xtremcool-and-udid).

Answer (score 0):

To add Footer of gridview for some particular page you need to right code in view as **(Review comment : //In order to add footer down to gridview for particular pages start)**

```
Ext.define("App.view.tabs.PurchaseReport", {
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
 alias: "widget.PurchaseReportTab",
 requires: [
    "App.model.PurchaseReport", "Ext.toolbar.Toolbar"],
 border: false,
 layout: "fit",
 items: [
    App.Util.buildBrowseConfig({}, {
    controller: "PurchaseReport",
    primaryKeyField: "PurchaseReportId",
    stateful: true,
    stateId: "App.view.windows.PurchaseReport-grid",

    columns: [
      { dataIndex: "PurchaseCost", filter: true, header: "Purchase Cost", width: 150 }
    ],
    features: [{ ftype: "filters", autoReload: false, local: true }],
    store: { model: "App.model.PurchaseReport", sorters: [{ property: "Name", direction: "asc" }],
       //In order to add footer down to gridview for particular pages start
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        bbar: [
        {
            dataIndex:"PurchaseCost",
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'Total',
            fieldLabel: 'Total',
            allowBlank: false
        }
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
       //In order to add footer down to gridview for particular pages end
  }
})
]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.feature.Summary', {

/* Begin Definitions */

extend: 'Ext.grid.feature.AbstractSummary',

alias: 'feature.summary',

/* End Definitions */

/**
 * Gets any fragments needed for the template.
 * @private
 * @return {Object} The fragments
 */
getFragmentTpl: function() {
    // this gets called before render, so we'll setup the data here.
    this.summaryData = this.generateSummaryData(); 
    return this.getSummaryFragments();
},

/**
 * Overrides the closeRows method on the template so we can include our own custom
 * footer.
 * @private
 * @return {Object} The custom fragments
 */
getTableFragments: function(){
    if (this.showSummaryRow) {
        return {
            closeRows: this.closeRows
        };
    }
},

/**
 * Provide our own custom footer for the grid.
 * @private
 * @return {String} The custom footer
 */
closeRows: function() {
    return '</tpl>{[this.printSummaryRow()]}';
},

/**
 * Gets the data for printing a template row
 * @private
 * @param {Number} index The index in the template
 * @return {Array} The template values
 */
getPrintData: function(index){
    var me = this,
        columns = me.view.headerCt.getColumnsForTpl(),
        i = 0,
        length = columns.length,
        data = [],
        active = me.summaryData,
        column;

    for (; i < length; ++i) {
        column = columns[i];
        column.gridSummaryValue = this.getColumnValue(column, active);
        data.push(column);
    }
    return data;
},

/**
 * Generates all of the summary data to be used when processing the template
 * @private
 * @return {Object} The summary data
 */
generateSummaryData: function(){
    var me = this,
        data = {},
        store = me.view.store,
        columns = me.view.headerCt.getColumnsForTpl(),
        i = 0,
        length = columns.length,
        fieldData,
        key,
        comp;

    for (i = 0, length = columns.length; i < length; ++i) {
        comp = Ext.getCmp(columns[i].id);
        data[comp.dataIndex] = me.getSummary(store, comp.summaryType, comp.dataIndex, false);
    }
    return data;
}
```

});